# Android, Type argument listadapter

Tags: android, kotlin, listadapter, android-room

so i'm following a guide online to make a room db. In the adapter section i followed his way of doing it but when i did it, i keep having the "No Type Argument expected for Interface ListAdapter".

Error example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vTMv.jpg

Here's the whole project so far on github.

https://github.com/OlivierLabelle/BudgetProject/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/budgetproject

And the guide i was following.

https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you should replace `ListAdapter<Transaction>` with `ListAdapter<Transaction, Viewholder>`.

You can see an example in the docs here :(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html), where ListAdapter has 2 arguments inside the diamonds: one for the list-object and the other for your custom viewholder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 17):

So with the help of devboi, i found out i was using the wrong import.

In the top right corner on the Dev documentation it show the right import.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Mfv.jpg

And here how the import on my project should look like.

```
import android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter
```

Answer (score 14):

Just came across this very problem myself.

If you're using AndroidX/Jetpack/whatever the official name is I'm still new at this, Android Studio might
`import android.widget.ListAdapter`
automatically, but the one you want is
`import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`